# CSS HTML Position absolute solution

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am trying to create a responsive design and using the position absolute to place my image in the right position. Now, is there a way to "lock down" two images to resize together with the size of the screen? I have to keep adjusting the image position using the @media query.

It's driving me insane now. What I want to achieve is both images to move together at the same time.

Have a look at this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gtmomt6b/) or see the demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 900px;
}

.absolutecontainerliquids {
  height: 450px;
}

.basecloudcontainer {
  position: relative;
}

.paddingtop {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.liquids {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 80%;
}

.cloud {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.darkgrey {
  background-color: #262626;
}

.lightgrey {
  background-color: #cfcdc7;
}

.page1 {
  z-index: 10;
}

.page2 {
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.firstimagetabletlogostripes {
  display: none;
}

.firstimagelogobottom {
  display: none;
}

.firstimagelogo {
  width: 64%;
  left: 18%;
  top: 27%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.blacktext {
  color: black;
}

.paragraph {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 340px) {
  .firstimagelogo {
    width: 65%;
    top: 25%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .firstimagelogo {
    width: 30%;
    top: 30%;
    left: 35%;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  .firstimagemlogostripes {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .firstimagetabletlogostripes {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -35%;
    top: 0%;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 120%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .firstimagetabletlogostripes {
    top: -10%;
    left: -40%
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .wrapper {
    overflow: visible;
  }
  .absolutecontainerliquids {
    height: 650px;
  }
  .firstimagetabletlogostripes {
    top: -20%;
    left: -45%;
    width: 130%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .firstimagetabletlogostripes {
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    width: 130%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .firstimagetabletlogostripes {
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    width: 130%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .firstimagetabletlogostripes {
    top: -60%;
    left: -30%;
    width: 120%;
  }
  .firstimagelogo {
    width: 20%;
    top: 25%;
    left: 40%;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  .firstimagelogotop {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -0%;
    left: 70%;
    width: 40%;
  }
  .firstimagelogobottom {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70%;
    left: 15%;
    width: 40%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <title>Base - E-Liquid</title>
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper darkgrey page1">
    <div class="container">
      <img class="firstimagemlogostripes" src="https://image.ibb.co/g5WJ66/mlogostripes.png" />
      <img class="firstimagetabletlogostripes" src="https://preview.ibb.co/gFnrR6/stripes.png" />
      <img class="firstimagelogo" src="https://image.ibb.co/gsPGtm/logofilled.png" />
      <img class="firstimagelogobottom" src="https://preview.ibb.co/gkXEeR/imagelogobottom.png" />
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="wrapper lightgrey page2">
    <div class="container absolutecontainerliquids">
      <div class="paragraph blacktext">
        <p>Ecstatic advanced and procured civility not absolute put continue. Overcame breeding or my concerns removing desirous so absolute. My melancholy unpleasing imprudence considered in advantages so impression. Almost unable put piqued talked likely
          houses her met. Met any nor may through resolve entered. An mr cause tried oh do shade happy.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: do you want second image to overlap on another ??

Comment: Yes, I do want the images to go over to the second page :) It's the logo and the stripes behind it that I struggle with :/

Comment: so i think you can photoshop them and combine it with one image

Comment: I think I am going to do it that way, I was just curious if there is a css/html solution for it :p

Comment: I tried too, but it was complex just to make it responsive on all devices. i think photoshop is the best solution here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use div tag and put your both image in it. If you are using external css then create a class and apply that class to both of images.

**Update:**

This is Html file:

```
<div class="bck">
   <div class="image-1"></div>
 </div>
```

And css:

```
.bck{
  background-image="image url"}

  .image-1{
   margin-top: 40px
   margin-left: 40px}
```

Comment: can you give me and actual code example that applies here?

Comment: See below code for reference. It's not proper code but you can have logic behind it. @BareFeet

Comment: I have added your code this answer, please delete the other to keep everything neat. Thank for your answer I will try that and let you know how it went.

Answer (score 0):

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="bck">
   <div class="image-1"></div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.bck {
    background-image="image url"
}

.image-1 {
    margin-top: 40px
    margin-left: 40px
}
```